# Is it possible to write something on Notepad++ and make it substitute when compiling?

Tags: notepad++

I'm using Notepad++ to write LaTeX documents. I plan to use it as a preview to some articles I'm going to write on Quora. Quora have a math mode to whatever is inside `[math][/math]` and the habitual math mode on LaTeX environments is `$ $` and `\[ \]`. Is it possible to type `[math][/math]` on Notepad++ but make it *understand* it as `$ $` or `\[ \]` when compiling?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your compilation is triggered, but you obviously need a pre-processing stage before compiling. Thus, the file you edit may have for instance `.quora.tex` extension so that editor still see it as a *LaTex* file (`.tex`) and at the same time the standard `.tex` will be reserved for the compilable version of your file:

```
 my_file.quora.tex =[pre-proc.]=> my_file.tex =[compile]=> my_file.dvi
```

This pre-processing stage would consist in transforming your custom syntax to standard syntax. In the case you mentioned, the following `sed` substitution command should suit your need:

```
cat my_file.quora.tex     \
| sed 's/\[math\]/\\\[/g'  \
| sed 's/\[\/math\]/\\\]/g' \
> my_file.tex
```

To trigger and chain these stages, good old [`make`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40738/how-to-properly-make-a-latex-project) tool seems the most standard solution to me.

Of course my answer is Unix oriented whereas Notepad++ is a Windows only editor, but since you are a LaTeX user you should manage to apply the same idea to a Windows envionment (by creating a `.bat` instead of a `Makefile` and finding a DOS replacement for `sed`, or installing a [`MinGW`](http://www.mingw.org/) environment or even a virtualized [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) using [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)).